# Trying to send push notifications using GCM from a windows service to IOS devices

Tags: c#, ios, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Hello

I would like to share with you an issue that I'm facing right now with the push notification, I have two mobile applications one Android and the other IOS. I need to send push notification to both depend on the database information. For the Android app I used the following code:

```
public string SendNotification(string deviceId, string message)
    {
        string GoogleAppID = "AIzaSyBvDvWXzvY38VyZN8M67YASQWK27ew7pY8";
        var SENDER_ID = "305958970287";
        var value = message;
        WebRequest tRequest;
        tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));

        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

        string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + deviceId + "";
        Console.WriteLine(postData);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

        tReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
        return sResponseFromServer;
    }
```

This code works perfectly fine, I received all the push notifications in the devices.

To use GCM for IOS app I follow all the steps describe in:

[GCM Documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start?ver=swift)

The code to send the notifications is exactly the same for the android app, the only change is the API Key and the sender parameter of course.

The problem is that for IOS app I don't receive the notifications, when I run the windows service I got this from the StreamReader **tReader**:

`"id=0:1453902236602583%46569b4366d6cf16"`. I don't get any exception in the code, everything seems to be ok but it doesn't work.

Note: I don't get any error in the code and any exception.

In the IOS app I get the Registration Token and everything I need, so I suppose that all the configuration process is correct.

IOS code:

```
 // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // Configure the Google context: parses the GoogleService-Info.plist, and initializes
    // the services that have entries in the file
    var configureError:NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
    gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID
    print(gcmSenderID!)
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    // Register for remote notifications
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
    UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    // [END register_for_remote_notifications]
    // [START start_gcm_service]
    let gcmConfig = GCMConfig.defaultConfig()
    gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self
    GCMService.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(gcmConfig)
    // [END start_gcm_service]
```

Getting the registration token:

```
func registrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {
    if (registrationToken != nil) {
        self.registrationToken = registrationToken
        let preferences = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let forKeyPath = SESSION_DATA + "_NOTIFICATIONTOKEN"
        _ = preferences.setObject(registrationToken, forKey: forKeyPath)
        _ = preferences.synchronize()
        print("Registration Token: \(registrationToken)")
        self.subscribeToTopic()
        let userInfo = ["registrationToken": registrationToken]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    } else {
        print("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    }
}
```

APN Test Result:

> 2016-02-02 15:07:43 +0000: loaded document aps_development.cer 
>   2016-02-02 15:07:50 +0000: Connected to server
>   gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com  2016-02-02 15:07:50 +0000: Set SSL
>   connection  2016-02-02 15:07:50 +0000: Set peer domain name
>   gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com  2016-02-02 15:07:50 +0000: Keychain
>   Opened   2016-02-02 15:07:50 +0000: Certificate  data  for Apple
>   Development IOS Push Services: com.jperera.RapidSentryMaster
>   initialized successfully  2016-02-02 15:07:50 +0000: Sec Identity
>   created  2016-02-02 15:07:50 +0000: Client certificate created 
>   2016-02-02 15:07:58 +0000: Connected  2016-02-02 15:07:58 +0000:
>   Token: <00000001 0000000c 000001bf bf010000 000001bf bf010000 000001bf
>   bf010000 000001bf bf010000 000001bf bf010000 000001bf 000000d8
>   d8000000 000000d8 0000000f 0f000000 0000000f>  2016-02-02 15:07:58
>   +0000: Written 92 bytes sending data to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195    2016-02-02 15:07:58 +0000:
>   Disconnected from server gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195

I will appreciate any help on that

Comment: Is that the messageId? Are there other messages that can be helpful for the community? Can you check out [GCM diagnostics](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en) thru Google Play Service developer console to see if that entry is there? If its GCM related, it can have the messageId there and the status on why it seems the iOS app hasn't received the notification. Hope this helps!

Comment: @adjuremods thank you very much for your answer, I'm going to check the GCM diagnostic, and I will let you know.

Comment: @adjuremods, I can't check with GCM diagnostics thru google play console because the application is an IOS app, and can't be upload to google play. In android everything works fine, the problem is in the IOS app

Comment: I think the GCM diagnostics should still be able to provide information useful to your issue since the iOS app is just a client. If you've done the registration of client app, from what I know it should display messageIds and status on the diagnostic. If this isn't the case it probably is an APNS issue.

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera How does your C# code find the certificate (which you got from Apple)? Or are you uploading that to Google in another way?

Comment: @MagnusSmith, I'm configuring everything in the google gcm process, I upload the certificates from apple, and generate the project in google developer console. One thing I suppose all the configuration works because  I get the registration token and everything

Comment: So you're using the PLIST file that Google gave you after you uploaded the .P12 file? It might be worth checking the certificate is correct before you use Google at all. I found a APN tester app in the (Mac) App Store, and it takes your .CER file and token value (64 chars of hex) to see if a notifcation makes it onto the iPhone or iPad OK.

Comment: thank you @MagnusSmith, I'm going to check the APN tester you found to see what happen. And yes, I have the google file .plist that google gave me. But the weird is that the registration and everything else works fine, just I don't receive the notification...

Comment: Oh wait, you mean you get "success:1,failure:0" back from the call to https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send ? I thought you saw an error.

Comment: @MagnusSmith, No I don't get any error on my code if you check my c# method, I'm getting as a server response: `"id=0:1453902236602583%46569b4366d6cf16"`, I don't know exactly what that means.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! The response you get looks familiar to me.

When I call GCM with a HTTP `POST` to send some JSON, then I get this JSON response back...  `{"multicast_id":5557NNN163626712336,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1451239821391315%e0bf69ABC9fd7ecd"}]}`
...and the last part looks the same as the response you get.

I believe this is GCM telling you everything went OK and this is the `Message ID` you can use in the GCM Diagnostics Tool if you want to (part of the Google Play Developer Console). Do you get any headers back from your web request, telling you the `multicast_id` or the number of success/failures?

[image]

This tool might reveal what happened to your message. It isn't perfect but it can be a help. Maybe GCM thinks your message was sent OK, but it failed later on, whilst in the hands of Apple, before reaching your iOS device?

One thing you may want to watch out for is that GCM has two ways to configure the payload (what I do with JSON, and you do with `&data.message=" + value`) and you might want to try using `notification` instead. See the 'payload' section at https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options which I confess I do not fully understand yet!

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I think you are right I have to check your suggestion..., I'm going to do it right now and let you know.

Comment: Let me ask you something, when I tried to get the same option for GCM Diagnostics, you need to have your application uploaded to Google console, and I don't have an application, remember the application is for IOS and the notification is sent from a Windows Service in C#, how can I make that test?

Comment: At the top of your question you said you had an Android app too. If you haven't added it to Google Play yet, I am not sure you can use GCM Diagnostics. You have to 'link' your GCM account with your Play developer account. Sorry! But once you do, you can use Diagnostics for iOS message IDs too, I believe.

Comment: Did you have any luck using an APN testing app from the Mac Store? That will prove if your Apple certificates are correct.

Comment: Yes you are right I have an android app, I didn't upload to the console yet, but with the android app I don't have problem it works fine, the problem is with IOS version

Comment: I'm going to check in the apple APN testing to see if everything is working fine.

Comment: I added the APN test result I'm new with this tool so I don't get the idea of what is happened, but also I don't received the notification neither

Comment: The APNS tool should ask you for a .cer file (the which you got from Apple, and previously used to generate a .p12 file to upload to GCM). Then you can enter a token (called `deviceId` in your C# code) and a title/message. Press SEND....and hope....